# How to profile multiple subprocesses using Python multiprocessing and memory_profiler?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, memory-profiling

I have a utility that spawns multiple workers using the Python [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) module, and I'd like to be able to track their memory usage via the excellent [`memory_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) utility, which does everything I want - particularly sampling memory usage over time and plotting the final result (I'm not concerned with the line-by-line memory profiling for this question).

In order to setup this question, I have created a simpler version of the script, that has a worker function which allocates memory similar to the [example](https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler/blob/master/examples/example.py) given in the `memory_profiler` library. The worker is as follows:

```
import time

X6 = 10 ** 6
X7 = 10 ** 7

def worker(num, wait, amt=X6):
    """
    A function that allocates memory over time.
    """
    frame = []

    for idx in range(num):
        frame.extend([1] * amt)
        time.sleep(wait)

    del frame
```

Given a sequential workload of 4 workers as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    worker(5, 5, X6)
    worker(5, 2, X7)
    worker(5, 5, X6)
    worker(5, 2, X7)
```

Running the `mprof` executable to profile my script takes 70 seconds having each worker run one after the other. The script, run as follows:

```
$ mprof run python myscript.py
```

Produces the following memory usage graph:

[image: Sequential Memory Generating Workers]

Having these workers go in parallel with `multiprocessing` means that the script will finish as slow as the slowest worker (25 seconds). That script is as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool    = mp.Pool(processes=4)
    tasks   = [
        pool.apply_async(worker, args) for args in
        [(5, 5, X6), (5, 2, X7), (5, 5, X6), (5, 2, X7)]
    ]

    results = [p.get() for p in tasks]
```

Memory profiler does indeed work, or at least there are no errors when using `mprof` but the results are a bit strange:

[image]

A quick look at Activity Monitor shows that in fact there are 6 Python processes, one for `mprof` one for `python myscript.py` and then one for each worker subprocess. It appears that `mprof` is only measuring the memory usage for the `python myscript.py` process.

[image: Python Processes in Activity Monitor]

The `memory_profiler` library is highly customizable, and I'm pretty confident that I should be able to capture the memory of each process and possibly write them out to separate log files by using the library itself. I'm just not sure where to begin or how to approach that level of customization.

**EDIT**

After reading through the `mprof` script I did discover the `-C` flag which sums up the memory usage of all child (forked) processes. This leads to a (much improved) graph as follows:

[image: Multiprocessing Workers with Include Children Flag]

But what I'm looking for is the memory usage of each individual subprocess over time so that I can plot all workers (and the master) on the same graph. My idea is to have each subprocess `memory_usage` written to a different log file, which I can then visualize.

Comment: This question is being discussed with the developers on GitHub at https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler/issues/118 if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As of today, a new feature has been added to the memory profiler library that does exactly this. If you need this functionality, first update memory_profiler as follows:

```
$ pip install -U memory_profiler
```

This should install the v0.44 release of memory profiler. To check that this is the case, use the help command on the run action:

```
mprof run --help
Usage: mprof run [options]

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --python              Activates extra features when the profiling executable
                        is a Python program (currently: function
                        timestamping.)
  --nopython            Disables extra features when the profiled executable
                        is a Python program (currently: function
                        timestamping.)
  -T INTERVAL, --interval=INTERVAL
                        Sampling period (in seconds), defaults to 0.1
  -C, --include-children
                        Monitors forked processes as well (sum up all process
                        memory)
  -M, --multiprocess    Monitors forked processes creating individual plots
                        for each child
```

If you see the `-M` flag then you're good to go!

You can then run the your script as follows:

```
$ mprof run -M python myscript.py
$ mprof plot
```

And you should get a figure that looks like this:

[image: mprof tracking individual child proccesses]

Note that if you use the `--include-children` flag as well, the main process memory will be the total memory usage of the all the children and main, which is also a helpful plot.

Comment: special thanks to @fabian-pedregosa for helping make this happen!

Comment: How about enabling timestamps and the `@profile` decorator in this mode? Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about enabling timestamps? I think this should be possible with the `@profile` decorator, it uses the same arguments.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not get it to work. Please take a look at https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler/issues/148

Comment: Ah, yeh I see the problem -- that was a very good bug report btw. Unfortunately the pickle problem crops up everywhere when dealing with different types of multiprocess profiling. Sorry about that.

Comment: is there a way to have names for the child processes? `child-n` is not really explanatory :)

Comment: That would be great if there was some way - I think you might have to dive into the details of cprofile to see if there is any way to do that.

Comment: @fabian-pedregosa Can we automatically save this plot ?

Comment: I found a package [TAMPPA](https://pypi.org/project/TAMPPA/) for saving the results of the memory-profiler and line-profiler as csv... good for future use :) Hope it helps